# Creating surface in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a variable named say `P` which is simply a n*3 matrix. It stores x,y,z coordinates for a contour plot, its like a closed loop. Now I have several matrices like `P` which slice my object. What I would like is to create a surface using these contour points. `scatter3()` does not really give a good representation. The issue using `surf()`  is that since I have contour coordinates, the coordinates are unordered. So the plot obtained using `surf()` is not the actual closed surface of my figure. How can I resolve this? Let's brainstorm.

Comment: the only way I can think of is kind of merging the matrices. I mean all the matrices are of different sizes - (n*3) where n is different for each of them. So instead of stacking the matrices on top of each other, I can some how merge them

Comment: No brainstorming needed. Look at the picture example for gridfit. It was created directly from contour data. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit